# Support in rr-debugger for not recording a subprocess?

Tags: linux, debugging, process, gdb

I am using Mozilla's rr-debugger to record a relatively simple process that forks and exec's a heavyweight subprocess. I only want to record the initial process. Since it only interacts with the subprocess by reading its stdout, it would be more efficient (record logs and cpu-wise) to leave the subprocess out from the record trace. Is this possible ? By default rr records the complete process tree apparently.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by modifying the subproces command lines so instead of `mainapp` forking and running `subapp --subargs`, `mainapp` runs `rr record --nested=release subapp --subargs`.

`--nested=release` will result in the inner `rr` running the child without recording it.